# Render a previously submitted event registration

Tags: civievent, drupal, quickform

I would like to display to the user their existing event registrations in a format similar to what they see on the "Thank-you" screen &/or receive in the confirmation email. There are multiple event registrations that have different profiles and all use Price Sets.

Ideally, I'd like to create a function that takes the id of a Participant record and returns the formatted HTML that we see on the Thank-you screen; then I'd call this for each of the user's Participant records.

Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is not straight forward solution for this. However you can certainly achieve this by 
1. Register URL in xml
2. Create a page and copy template from thank you page of event.
3. Assign all the required variables to smarty template.

HTH

Pradeep